# Tensorflow: exclude an op for backward pass

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to create simple 4-layer(including input layer) neural network in tensorflow to work on MNIST data. It works well with following graph definition,

Graph1

```
with tf.name_scope("layer1"):
    z1 = tf.matmul(x,w1) + b1
    a1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(z1)
with tf.name_scope("layer2"):
    z2 = tf.matmul(a1,w2) + b2
    a2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(z2)
with tf.name_scope("layer3"):
    z3 = tf.matmul(a2,w3) + b3
```

Next, I want to perform some operation after each activation and I create a graph as below,

Graph2

```
with tf.name_scope("layer1"):
    x = transform(x)
    z1 = tf.matmul(x,w1) + b1
    a1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(z1)
with tf.name_scope("layer2"):
    a1 = transform(a1)
    z2 = tf.matmul(a1,w2) + b2
    a2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(z2)
with tf.name_scope("layer3"):
    a2 = transform(a2)
    z3 = tf.matmul(a2,w3) + b3
```

where, transform is a python function defined with tensorflow ops to generate same size output matrix as that of input matrix with some mathematical transformation. Graph1 trains well and I get very good performance on it, but the problem with Graph2 is that only "layer3" becomes trainable i.e. w3 and b3 and tensorflow excludes other variables from training set. I tried adding var_list to optimizer but no luck. `tf.stop_gradient` works with variables but how to use it for a python function?  More specifically, I want to exclude "tranform" function itself for backward pass and only use it in forward pass. On this [link](https://imgur.com/a/hUUGB) you will find graphs created in tensorboard. Is there any way to do this in tensorflow? TIA!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have come to conclusion that it is not possible to do it in tensorflow because, tensorflow internally builds a graph structure which will be traversed backward completely unless there is `tf.stop_gradient` call at some point. So one has to write their own forward and backward pass both. Hope this helps someone in future!!